# Error on Cabal Build: Failed to build plutus-core-0.1.0.0

Tags: cabal, marlowe, marlowe-pioneer-program, m1

Following the instructions from https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-pioneer-program, yet on a Mac M1, running `cabal build` from within `/marlowe-pioneer-program/code main` generates 2 errors:

1. `Failed to build byron-spec-ledger-0.1.0.0.` (According to the build profile, this is the first item to be built.) The log for this error reads:

```
Configuring library for byron-spec-ledger-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for byron-spec-ledger-0.1.0.0..
Building library for byron-spec-ledger-0.1.0.0..
[ 1 of 16] Compiling Byron.Spec.Ledger.Core ( src/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Core.hs,     dist/build/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Core.o, dist/build/Byron/Spec/Ledger/Core.dyn_    o )
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/dlindberg/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/lib/libHScrd    n-crypt-clss-2.0.0-3518c5de-ghc8.10.7.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in fl    at namespace '_crypto_generichash_blake2b'
```

2. `Failed to build plutus-core-0.1.0.0.` (Third item to be built). Log for this error:

```
Warning: plutus-core.cabal:312:23: visibility is experimental feature (issue
#5660)
Configuring library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
Building library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
[  1 of 191] Compiling Crypto           ( plutus-core/src/Crypto.hs, dist/bu    ild/Crypto.o, dist/build/Crypto.dyn_o )
[  2 of 191] Compiling Data.Aeson.Flatten ( plutus-core/src/Data/Aeson/Flatt    en.hs, dist/build/Data/Aeson/Flatten.o, dist/build/Data/Aeson/Flatten.dyn_o     )
[  3 of 191] Compiling Data.Aeson.THReader ( plutus-core/src/Data/Aeson/THRe    ader.hs, dist/build/Data/Aeson/THReader.o, dist/build/Data/Aeson/THReader.dy    n_o )
[  4 of 191] Compiling Data.ByteString.Hash ( plutus-core/src/Data/ByteStrin    g/Hash.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Hash.o, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Has    h.dyn_o )
[  5 of 191] Compiling Data.SatInt      ( plutus-core/src/Data/SatInt.hs, di    st/build/Data/SatInt.o, dist/build/Data/SatInt.dyn_o )
[  6 of 191] Compiling ErrorCode        ( common/ErrorCode.hs, dist/build/Er    rorCode.o, dist/build/ErrorCode.dyn_o )
[  7 of 191] Compiling PlutusCore.Builtin.Emitter ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCo    re/Builtin/Emitter.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Builtin/Emitter.o, dist/build/P    lutusCore/Builtin/Emitter.dyn_o )
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following [this](https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1) guide, it's specific for Mac M1